# Getting total Records in database

Tags: rowcount

```
public ResultSet getRecordsCount(){
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {
        result = statement.executeQuery("Select count(word) from records");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm trying to get total number of rows in my database but it is returning garbage value.
I'm Using SQL Server 2012 and there is no exception in the code.
Is my code correct?

Comment: To know if your code is right we need to know which database you are querying to (Access, SQL server, Oracle, MySQL, PostGre-SQL, SQLite..) and then which error (printStackTrace()) it gives you

Comment: SQL Server 2012
There are No Exceptions in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this code:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public static void main(String[] args) {

  int numRows = 0; 

  try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String userName = "user"; //in case you need
    String password = "password"; // in case you need
    String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433"+";databaseName=THE_NAME_OF_MY_DB";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    // if you don't need user and password then
    // Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
    ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

    // This while loop is to loop over each row and the for loop
    // is to loop over each field
    while (rs.next()) {

      for(int i=1; i <= rs.getColumnCount(); i++){

        numRows ++;
        System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
        //This prints field by field
      }
    }

    System.out.println(Total column number"+rs.getColumnCount());
    System.out.println(Total row number"+Integer.toString(numRows));

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: But this isn't returning the total number of rows in the database.